# for-each loop in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Please excuse me, I'm no expert in XSLT (AT ALL) so this could be really really bad but...

I have my xml (for example)

```
<tests>
    <test seq="1">
        <foo name="foo1" />
        <bar name="bar1" />
    </test>
    <test seq="2">
        <foo name="foo2" />
        <bar name="bar2" />
    </test>
    <test seq="1">
        <foo name="foo3" />
        <bar name="bar3" />
    </test>
<tests>
```

and I have my xslt (again for example)

```
    <xsl:template match="dptest">
        <xsl:for-each select="/tests/test">
            <p>
                Sequence:<xsl:value-of select="@seq"/><br/>
                <b>Name Of Foo:</b><xsl:value-of select="/foo/@name"/> and <b>Name Of Bar:</b><xsl:value-of select="/bar/@name"/>
            </p>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

and I'm wanting to spit out...

> Sequence:1
>      **Name Of Foo: foo1** and **Name Of
>   Bar:**bar1
>
> Sequence:2
>      **Name Of Foo: foo2** and
>   **Name Of Bar:**bar2
>
> Sequence:3
>      **Name Of Foo:
>   foo3** and **Name Of Bar:**bar3

But I'm getting ...

> Sequence:1
>      **Name Of Foo:**  and **Name Of Bar:**
>
> Sequence:2
>      **Name Of Foo:**  and **Name Of
>   Bar:**
>
> Sequence:3
>      **Name Of Foo:**  and **Name
>   Of Bar:**

if anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it MASSIVELY :)

Cheers

Daz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use a full path

```
select="/foo/@name"
```

but a relative path

```
select="foo/@name"
```

Comment: I've worked it out and I'm stupid :) I had already tried doing what you suggested before and it wasn't working.. i have JUST noticed the reason it wasn't working is because I had ..

select="foo/@Name"

god dam case sensitive code  :)

I will still accept your answer though as you are indeed correct, so thanks for your help Pierre ;)